# C++ eclipse building error

Tags: c++, eclipse, ubuntu, build

I'm programming with Galileo on Ubuntu.

My project is compiled through the terminal fine. But for the nice features of eclipse I decided to use eclipse. So I copied and pasted everything inside an eclipse project directory. Then I refreshed the project in the project explorer and everything was found by eclipse. (EDITED) But a red mark  (the error mark) is shown on the project icon and when I build the project no binary file is created.

And the last thing is that all the files inside the project have no errors!

what's the problem?

Comment: What does the error log have in it? What is the exact message you are seeing.

Comment: How could I see the error log?

Comment: I said that in a bad manner, eclipse says nothing, it just displays a red mark showing that there's some problem with the project. If there's some error log anywhere else tell me to check it please.

Comment: @DanS: yes ... It's a makefile project

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Presumably it is a makefile project. Have you set up the Eclipse IDE to use make with the correct make arguments?

Have you set up the path for the include and lib directories that you need?

Right click on the project in the tree viewer and bring up the preferences dialog and make sure.

There is a console output tab on the Eclipse IDE. What does that say?

There is also a Problems tab that sorts the compiler output. What is on this?

Comment: Many thanks ... Yes It's a makefile project. I've set up the include paths. But both the console and Problems windows say: make: *** No rule to make target `main.o', needed by `net-prj2'.  Stop.

Comment: Now that error is fixed :) But the functions I've called from lpthread library are not defined. How can I fix it?

Comment: There are sub-pages on the project settings tree that let you add extra library paths. Check that the makefile sets the paths up as absolute paths.

Answer (score 0):

There could well be a problem with building it a a whole project, maybe a link error? More likely it has not been set up properly for eclipse.

Are you using helios? Autotools?

Comment: Probably not, I've not even heard of helios and autotools :D

Comment: Helios is the next version of Eclipse after Galileo.